# Converting string to float with Python

Tags: python

```
#I have a string array as,
ele =["o","al","ag",'fe']

#And defined a float variable as,
eqoo = float(2.540761)

stre1 = ele[0]
stre2 = ele[0]
eqdist = ("eq"+str(stre1)+str(stre2))

print float(eqdist)
```

The above print statement gives me the error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plotdistorg.py", line 64, in <module>
    print float(eqdist)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: eqoo
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you're trying to convert text to a float (numbers)...?

Comment: eqdist = `eqoo` and that **cannot** be a float. What are you trying to do?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to build the variable name as a string. That's not how it works. A string can't be used as a variable name.

Comment: What do you expect `float('eqoo')` to do?

Comment: Try: `print float(eval('eqoo'))`

Comment: @MalikBrahimi usage of eval is dangerous

Comment: @VigneshKalai Yes I know, but it is what he intends to do.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi look at the answer eval should be used only when there is no other way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to get variable `eqoo`'s value. Variable name `eqoo` and string value `"eqoo"` are different things.

If you want to get variable `eqoo`'s value:

```
>>> globals()[eqdist]
2.540761
```

And if you want to convert it to float(in this case, it already is!)

```
>>> print float(globals()[eqdist])
2.540761
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I wanted to do.

Comment: @user3700 Glad you found it useful. It would be great if you closed the question by accepting the answer :)

Comment: @user3700 click the tickbox next to his answer to mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 3):

Converting to a float works... When you want numbers that are a string to be a float.

You can't convert text to a float.

Let me expand a little. A string can contatin anything:

```
'hello'
'123abc'
'3.141592'
```

But a float is quite specific:

```
3.141592
154.0
```

So you can convert a string to a float - if and only if *it entirely consists of numbers, a `-` or `+` sign and a `.`*.

Just because your string is made up of numbers, it's still a string, and will be treated as such untill you convert it to a float or an integer.

But if your string has any non numbers in it, it can't be a float - because a float is a decimal. From my example of strings, only the last one will let me turn it into a float. All the others do this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float: hello
```

By `could not convert string to float` it means that string contains a character that isn't valid in a float.

---

Your specific case? You set the value of a variable to the name of another one and print it like that:

```
var1='helloworld'
var2='var1'
print (var2)
```

would print `var1` not `helloworld`. If you want them to equal each other, you need this code:

```
var1='helloworld'
var2=var1
print (var2)
```

and then it would print `helloworld` because they both have that value.

Comment: How to fix this? I want to print the number inside the variable eqoo. That is 2.540761.

Comment: @user3700 Ahh, you can't just make the value of a variable the name of another and just print it. Python doesn't work like that.

Comment: @PeterWood good point, edited.